# How to delineate or extract complex noun phrases that include verb phrases in their makeup using SpaCy?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I know about the `noun_chunks` that's inbuilt in SpaCy. However it is not exactly suitable for the position I found myself in.
To give an example -

```
Skynet will be decommissioned soon.
```

This is a very simple sentence where `noun_chunks` will output *Skynet*.
Now lets replace *Skynet* with a *complex noun phrase*(for a lack of moniker to describe what I need) as follows -

```
The machine that kills life will be decommissioned soon.
```

So here `Skynet` -> `The machine that kills life`
However `noun_chunks` will identify `The machine` and `life` as noun phrases which is correct but I need something to extract `The machine that kills life`  as one complex noun phrase.

Using Dependency parse might help but I am not so sure how to go about doing this. Any direct help or a recommendation to read up on how to make use of dependency parse (more importantly the construction and grammatical relationships in English) so that I may solve this issue myself would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For now I am content with finding the **subtree** of the `nsubjpass` of the **root**. To handle more cases I may have to look at options other than `nsubjpass`, but I am yet to figure them out.

Using the [online dependency visualizer](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy) helped me figure this to a certain extent.
Code that gives me the complex noun phrase -

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

simple_np = "Skynet will be decommissioned soon."

complex_np = "The machine that kills life will be decommissioned soon."

doc = nlp(complex_np)

for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.root)
    for child in sent.root.children:
        if child.dep_ == 'nsubjpass':
            print(list(child.subtree))
```